# Is there a word for a person who has no influence?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one sole word for a person who has no influence in the world outside or make any valuable or notable contributions?

Example: "Most people are not addicted to their smartphones, they simply don't want to feel lonely or [being in that described state or being that kind of person]"

Comment: feel lonely or `unimportant`.

Comment: "Like a Mr. Nobody" maybe? Btw, you mean "Most people **are** addicted to their smartphones, ..."

Comment: Irrelevant, a nobody, just anybody, unremarkable, forgettable, disposable, schmoe?

Comment: “invisible” can be used figuratively to refer to somebody (or something) that is not perceived / recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person who has no influence in the world outside or make any valuable or notable contributions is

Insignificant.

in·sig·nif·i·cant
ˌinsiɡˈnifəkənt
adjective
too small or unimportant to be worth consideration.,
"the amount required was insignificant compared with military spending"
synonyms:   unimportant, trivial, trifling, negligible, inconsequential, of no account, inconsiderable;
 More
(of a person) without power or influence.
meaningless.
"insignificant yet enchanting phrases"

Answer (score 0):

**effete**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/effete)

**Depleted of vitality, force, or effectiveness; exhausted; *ineffectual***

> ... they simply don't want to feel lonely or being an **effete**
>   person.